# I need to change the value of a field and redirect to a url on button click. How am I supposed to do it?

Tags: django, django-models, django-ajax-selects

I am working on a problem where I need to change the value of a model field "verified" on button click and redirect it to mail url so the the verified users get mail. I am not familiar with ajax. Please help me out in doing this.

models.py:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Roles, default='client')
    verified =models.BooleanField(default = False,blank=True)
```

template:

```
 <td>

  < a class="btn btn-primary"><i class="feather icon-edit mr-1">Verify</i></a>
  <a class="btn btn-primary"><i class="feather icon-trash-2">Delete</a>
                                                        </td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to write a view that you can call in the HTML on the button click 
example :

```
from django.shortcuts import render    
from .models import UserProfile    
def verify_and_redirect(request) :
    prof = UserProfile()
    prof.verified = True 
    prof.save()
    return render(request,'app_name/male_tamplate.html', context=context)
```

Then you can map this view to a URL in your urls.py file as follows:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views    
path ('verify',views.verify_and_redirect, name='verify')
```

Then in your html, you can associate the URL with the button as follows:

```
 < a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'verify' %}"><i class="feather icon-edit mr-1">Verify</i></a>
```